# Why is my MultiSelectList not returning data to model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following View Model:

```
public class SendGroupEmailViewModel
{
    public int EmailID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedRoles { get; set; }

}
```

The controller action that sends the appropriate information to the view:

```
var viewModel = new SendGroupEmailViewModel
        {
            Roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Id.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList(),

        };
```

Then in my view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRoles, new MultiSelectList(Model.Roles, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "" })
```

The list appears correctly within the view but when the form with the above ListBoxFor in is posted SelectedRoles returns as null.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can remedy it?

Comment: What is the type of Id property in Role entity ?

Comment: It's a string, thanks very much for pointing out my issue, I feel pretty dumb!  edit - That obviously resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The only reason this won't work is because the SELECT element's option value's are not numeric type (EX : `Guid` /`String`). In that case the model binder will not be able to bind the non numeric value array to an int array type (Which is the type of your `SelectedRoles` property).

The solution is to change the  type of `SelectedRoles` to a collection of type which is the type of your `Id` property in `Role` entity.

Assuming your `Role.Id` is of `string` type, This should fix the problem

```
public class SendGroupEmailViewModel
{
    public int EmailID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
    public string [] SelectedRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Also you do not need to create an object of `MultiSelectList` in your view again. You can simply do

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRoles, Model.Roles, new { @class = "" })
```